# Correct JSON block output from Golang

Tags: go

I have search for a solution for this problem. It is actually from a sql database, but this illustrates the problem as well:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    m := map[string]string{
      "USER_ID":"JD", 
      "USER_NAME":"John Doe",
    }

    json, _ := json.Marshal(m)
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
       fmt.Println(string(json))
    }

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/7DQPiB0aWAK

Each row is correct, but it each row is not separated by comma and surrounded by square brackets.

```
{"USER_ID":"JD","USER_NAME":"John Doe"}
{"USER_ID":"JD","USER_NAME":"John Doe"}
{"USER_ID":"JD","USER_NAME":"John Doe"}
{"USER_ID":"JD","USER_NAME":"John Doe"}
```

The desired output is this:

```
[{"USER_ID":"JD","USER_NAME":"John Doe"},
{"USER_ID":"JD","USER_NAME":"John Doe"},
{"USER_ID":"JD","USER_NAME":"John Doe"},
{"USER_ID":"JD","USER_NAME":"John Doe"}]
```

Is this possible using map[string]string or interface?

Comment: You're marshalling the map once, then just repeatedly printing it.  How on earth would the json package know that it's part of a list?  If you want it to be a list, make it a `[]map[string]string`.  That, or manually print the brackets and commas.

Comment: @Kaedys is right, you don't use any list (slice), so you don't print any. Alternatively you could build your list and repeatedly append your map. 
`list := []map[string]string{};
list = append(list,m)`

Comment: Just in case, your current output is in [JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org/) format, and some tools are able to read it.

Comment: @skovorodkin "...and some tools are able to read it." That was what I thought, but the most common way seems to be the format [{},{}]. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @sibert, it depends. For instance, if you write output to a file and then run another tool to process it, using JSON Lines might be a better approach, because it's cheaper to parse an object per line, than a whole file at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this possible using map[string]string or interface?

The answer is simple - You can use a [slice](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7) whenever you want to produce a list output in JSON.

Here is your example with the desired output ([playground](https://play.golang.org/p/eNvMJ4ERm9s)) :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {
    // define a slice of maps
    var mySlice []map[string]string

    // define a map
    m := map[string]string{
      "USER_ID":"JD", 
      "USER_NAME":"John Doe",
    }

    // add the map 4 times to the slice
    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        mySlice = append(mySlice, m)
    }

    // print the slice
    json, _ := json.Marshal(mySlice)
    fmt.Println(string(json))
}
// Output: [{"USER_ID":"JD","USER_NAME":"John Doe"},{"USER_ID":"JD","USER_NAME":"John Doe"},{"USER_ID":"JD","USER_NAME":"John Doe"},{"USER_ID":"JD","USER_NAME":"John Doe"}]
```